# Access to superclass's constant

Tags: objective-c, case, constants, c-preprocessor

In my universal app in main AppDelegate class I define a constant:

```
#define kNumerOfPages 2
```

In AppDelegate_iPhone class and AppDelegate_iPad class I would have access to this constant like normal constant. Example:

```
switch (i) {
    case ([super kNumerOfPages]):
    {
        NSLog(@"FinalPage");
        break;
    }
}
```

Can I get access to it as a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` is a preprocessor directive which shows what tokens to replace with what values. You don't access it through objects at runtime. All you need to do is to include appropriate header file to the file you want to use that constant in. then just do the simple

```
switch (i) {
    case (kNumberOfPages) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean what I need to define two constants in each classes (_iPhone and _iPad)? It isn't beauty... I can write properties in superclass for get access to value of constant, but then I will not can use a `case`...

Comment: You cannot use instance variables in case statements because their values need to be known at compile time. Define your constant in Prefix.pch file. Then it will be accessible everywhere.

Comment: I know what I can not use instance variables. Prefix.pch - is a good advice. Thank you, Eimantas!